# how to update an formbuilder reactive form in angular

Tags: formbuilder, formgroups, angular16, patchvalue

```
this.hospitalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  docName: ['', Validators.required],
  PhoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
  specialty: ['', Validators.required],
  Education: ['', Validators.required],
  Gender: ['Male', Validators.required],
  NumberOfAppointments: ['', Validators.required],
  Status: ['Permanent', Validators.required],
  Address: ['', Validators.required],
  Email: ['', Validators.required],
  AvailabilityWeekdaysDay: ['', Validators.required],
  AvailabilityWeekendsDay: ['', Validators.required],
  AvailabilityWeekdaysTime: ['', Validators.required],
  AvailabilityWeekendsTime: ['',  Validators.required],
  ModifiedBy: [''],
  CreatedBy: [],
});
```

I have a form I want to edit the data of the form using form Builder but when I clicked on edit button I am not getting the data for edit the form there is no data in for edit but I am getting the data on console how to pass the data ?